# Can't reuse the value of previous type instead of None

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I've created a function in python to print some information through it. I'm trying to supply `list of alphabets` to the function along with the `type` those alphabets fall under.

As I'm not supplying the value of `type` from outer side of the function, I've defined it as None. However, when I execute the function, It checks whether the value of the type is None. If it is None, it executes the except block to fetch one.

Although the value of the type is None when an alphabet is supplied to the function, ain't there already the value of previous type (when run twice) stored in the memory.

I've tried with:

```
def get_info(alpha,alpha_type):

    print("checking value of item:",alpha_type)

    try:
        if not alpha_type:raise
        return alpha,alpha_type
    except Exception:
        alpha_type = "vowel"
        return get_info(alpha,alpha_type)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for elem in ["a","e","o"]:
        print(get_info(elem,alpha_type=None))
```

Output it produces:

```
checking value of item: None
checking value of item: vowel
('a', 'vowel')
checking value of item: None
checking value of item: vowel
('e', 'vowel')
checking value of item: None
checking value of item: vowel
('o', 'vowel')
```

Output I wish to have:

```
checking value of item: None
checking value of item: vowel
('a', 'vowel')
checking value of item: vowel
('e', 'vowel')
checking value of item: vowel
('o', 'vowel')
```

> How can I reuse the value of previous type instead of None?

Btw, I'm after any solution which keeps the existing design intact.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the existing design? Using exceptions instead of a simple if is overcomplicated and you seem to be doing all of it where you could just use a default parameter value. What's this supposed to be doing?

Comment: From your question it looks as though your function is already producing the correct output i.e. the pairs that it returns are exactly what you want, but you're (understandably) not happy with implementation approach? If that's not the case could you add an example where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are passing from the main `alpha_type=None` every time. If you want to pass the last returned value instead, change the main to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_type = None
    for elem in ["a","e","o"]:
        result = get_info(elem, alpha_type=main_type)
        main_type = result[1]
        print(result)
```

Output:

```
checking value of item: None
checking value of item: vowel
('a', 'vowel')
checking value of item: vowel
('e', 'vowel')
checking value of item: vowel
('o', 'vowel')
```

Comment: It appears to be working in the right way. Thanks a lot.